# Why can't we redirect output to an external log file from a gdb script?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I cannot redirect output to an external log file from a gdb script. For example:

main.c

```c
void func2(){  return; }
void func1(){ func2(); }

int main()
{
    func1();
    return 0;
}
```

gdb-script.py

```py
gdb.execute("rbreak main.c:.")
gdb.execute("set logging file ./test.log")
gdb.execute("set logging on")
gdb.execute("r")
```

Step1: Compile `main.c` with debug information: `$ gcc -g main.c`

Step2: Either `$ gdb a.out -x gdb-script.py` or `(gdb) source gdb-script.py` does not redirect output to `test.log`. i.e. `test.log` is blank.

However, as shown in the steps below, executing each command one by one in gdb interactive mode does work.

```
$ gdb a.out
(gdb) rbreak main.c:.
(gdb) set logging file ./test.log
(gdb) set logging on
(gdb) r
```

`test.log` :

```
Starting program: a.out 

Breakpoint 3, main () at main.c:6
6       func1();
```

Why does the gdb script not work? And also, how do I output result to an external log file by using gdb script?

Comment: I guess this issue is a bug.

Comment: I see the same output in `test.log` using either interactive mode of `gdb-script.py`. Please specify your version of GDB and the output you get in `test.log` using both methods.

Comment: @EmployedRussian
Using script get a blank `test.log`, but using interactive mode get non-blank `test.log`. (see edited OP). The version of gdb is 11.2.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Did you get the exact same `test.log` as me when using the gdb script?